# How not to run certain codes in BeforeAll for a specific Describe() block in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm working on a Jasmine unit test spec. There are multiple `describe()` blocks in the JS file.

In `BeforeAll`, I want to only call function for Describe-Block "A" and "C", so how can I do that? The logic is like this:

```
//SampleSpec.js
BeforeAll(function() {
        if(descirbe name !== "B"){
            DoSomething();
        }
});

descirbe("A", function() {
        //...
});

descirbe("B", function() {
        //..
});

descirbe("C", function() {
        //...
});
```

Comment: please add some code showing what you have tried. some links to what you have looked up. something to show that there was some effort on your end to solve this.

Comment: Improved the text formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your setup, `beforeAll` will always run. But you could create your own `sharedSetup()` function & just call it at the top of `A` and `C`, but not `B`.  If it is promise based, you can `sharedSetup.then()` to defer running the rest of your code until the promise resolves.

This is beneficial as it keeps the logic for a test clearly within that test, rather than having a conditional for the test elsewhere in the test file.